# Restore Windows 8.1 Installation

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, bsod

I have a broken Windows 8.1 installation. It fails to start with a BSOD.
Booting in safe mode, it says it cannot find a critical driver, intelide.sys.
Entering with a system rescue live cd I can mount the drives and find that intelide.sys is indeed missing in \Windows\System32\drivers, while it exists in a subdir of WinSXS.
 Unfortunately I cannot directly copy that file in the drivers directory because the NTFS has been left open and can be mounted only in readonly mode.
*What is the correct and working procedure to fix this problem,* without reinstalling everything to factory default (that btw would wipe away all partitioning)?
 *Is there a way to have a Microsoft console that allows to fix this error, and how?*

Thx-

Comment: Windows should automatically attempt to repair your installation, it's very likely that that process has failed or would fail, if you attempted to do it.  Your problem is caused by system file corrupt.  You can use DISM to scan and repair your installation from within the WinRE, have you tried that?

Comment: No, I did not try DISM, at the end I did it with a Win7 Live, where I installed a restore program. Much of the complication was due to the UEFI flag in the bios that prevented me to access to boot discs. Thank you

Comment: Why are you using a Windows 7 WinRE when you have Windows 8 installed?

Comment: It happaned that I had that one, what's the difference? I only needed it to run the backup program

Comment: There are significant changes between the WinRE based on Windows 7 and the one based on Windows 8 or Windows 10.  The DISM tool functionality is a major difference.  You cannot repair a windows installation with the Windows 7 DISM tool.

Comment: It's rather obvious that I cannot use the DISM tool on a system that has a different major version, as I said I just needed a platform to run a backup program. Thanks anyway, I'll keep in mind DISM functionalities for the next crash, let's stop this useless flame, now.

Comment: What flame?  You have answered my original comment question, have you attempted to repair the installation, from within the appropriate version of WinRE?